Why cannot I flag questions for migration to other SE sites besides Meta?
More than once I've tried to flag a question for migration to Math SE, Stack Overflow or Information Security SE. I do this by clicking on

flag $\rightarrow$ should be closed $\rightarrow$ off-topic because $\rightarrow$ This questions belongs to another site in the SE Network

but then I only get the option for Crypto-Meta SE.
Is this just a matter of reputation, or is it a feature we (the community) don't have yet? 
Thanks in advance.

Note that this is similar to all other SE sites; migration involves a lot of work it seems. Not that I'm agreeing with it; I certainly would have created a feature to choose any other related site (or even random SE site) using the Off topic -> belongs to another site option.

We've tried to get Stack Exchange to add migration paths in the past and have been told no (more or less).
Instead I recommend just flagging with "Other" and mention the site. 
Also see some of this info to help judge whether migration is appropriate.
